# If $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ satisfies $f'(x) <L$ for some $L<1$, then $f$ has a unique fixed point

Tags: real-analysis

Assume that $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$  is differentiable.

If there exists an $L<1$ such that for each $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $f'(x)<L$, prove that there exists a unique point $x$ such that $f(x)=x$.

So far I have that where I fixed $a$ to be zero and came up with three cases to show existence for

$f(0) = 0$, $f(0) < 0$, and $f(0) > 0$

$f(0)=0$ was fairly trivial following from the mean value theorem but the other two cases I was only able to eliminate half of the possible fixed points by contradiction and I need help showing it explicitly.

Edit as to avoid confusion here is the work I have garnished so far:

From the mean value theorem it follows for some arbitrary $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ and $a\neq b$ that there exists a point $c$ such that $a<c<b$ or $b<c<a$ then implies that $\frac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$ and this is because it is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$ and, by convention, is also continuous on $\mathbb{R}$ as well.

Then the result of $\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)$ then follows for $L<1$ such that $\forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ means $f'(x)<1$ from our hypothesis. Which then follows

(*) $\dfrac{f(b)-f(a)}{b-a}=f'(c)<L<1 \Rightarrow f(b)-f(a)<L(b-a)<b-a$

Now without loss of generality choose $a=0$ and let $b$ be some arbitrary value in $\mathbb{R}$ then there are three cases that need to be considered for the value of $f(a)$:

(i) $f(0) = 0$, (ii) $f(0) < 0$, (iii) $f(0) > 0$

(i) For $f(0)=0$

Then $0$ is a fixed point of point of $f(x)$ and it follows from (*) that if $f(0)=a=0$ then $f(b)-f(0)=f(b)<Lb<b$ which shows that $f(b)<b$ thus shows that for any arbitrary value $b\in \mathbb{R}$ that no $f(b)=b$ thus shows that $0$ is the only fixed point if $f(0)=0$

(ii) For $f(0)<0$

Suppose there exists a fixed point $d>0$ then:

$\frac{f(d)-f(0)}{d}<L<1 \Rightarrow d-f(0)< dL<d \Rightarrow -f(0)<d(L-1)<0\Rightarrow 0<-d(L-1)<f(0)$ but this contradicts that $f(0)<0$  thus no other fixed point exists if $d>0$ when $f(0)<0$

(iii) For $f(0)>0$

Comment: I can't see where you define $a$ in the question. Personally my first approach here would be to try and show this is a contraction mapping.

Comment: $0$ is not necessarily the fixed point. Consider the constant function $f(x) = 1$. Then $f'(x) = 0 < \frac{1}{2} < 1$ for all $x$ and $f(1) = 1$ so $1$ is the fixed point.

Comment: *Uniqueness*: suppose there are $x > y$ such that $f(x) = x$ and $f(y) = y$; then
$f(x) - f(y) = x-y$; but by assumption with the mean-value theorem we have
$f(x) - f(y) < (x-y)L < x-y$, a contradiction. 

*Existence*: See Greg Martin's proof below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the function $g(x)=x-f(x)$, which is differentiable and satisfies $g'(x) > \delta$ for some $\delta>0$ (namely $\delta=1-L$). Fixed points of $f$ are precisely the zeros of $g$. Now $g$ is increasing everywhere, so it can't have two distinct zeros (thanks to Rolle's theorem).

On the other hand, for $x>0$, we have $g(x)-g(0) = \int_0^x g'(x) \,dx > \int_0^x \delta\,dx = \delta x$; therefore $g(x)>0$ when $x$ is sufficiently positive. Similarly, $g(x)<0$ when $x$ is sufficiently negative. It follows from the intermediate value theorem that $g$ does have a zero.

Comment: @GudsonChou “so it can't have two distinct zeros”